# How can I make a keyboard piano vibrate its sound?

Tags: piano, keyboard, vibrato

How can I do this "vibrato" sound on a keyboard piano like at the start of "Minor" by Gracie Abrams?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you call vibrato is usually referred to as “tremolo”. It is an effect where the volume oscillates.

Many electronic keyboards have this as one of the available built-in effects. It is also standard with most Digital Audio Workstation software. And plenty of choice in tremolo stomp-box effect pedals too.

The keyboard in the song you mention seems to be a Wurlitzer sound. To illustrate: Here is a sample Wurlitzer (imitation) sound with tremolo effect.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p72st0lll5rmu9/wurlitzer_with_tremolo.mp3?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for putting me straight on my now-deleted answer. I confused Rhodes with Wurlitzer.

Comment: Come to think of it, the Hammond B3 was also famous for it's vibrato, yes?

Comment: That one is a varying frequency vibrato (or actually varying phase, to be more precise). Anyway, not the topic of the question.

Comment: @Aaron - Hammond B3 (and others) use the Leslie effect - quite complex in actuality, using rotating speaker baffle and horn. Sort of mi of vib and trem. Might be worh a question!

Comment: The Hammond organ has a Vibrato setting that's independent of the Leslie. Google for Hammond Vibrato Scanner. Brilliant concept!

Comment: thank you so much for helping me! wurlitzer pianos are expensive tho. do you have any other electronic pianos recommendations that have this tremolo sound too but at a low price?

Comment: @Amy do you already have a digital  piano? Need something to record or to perform live?

Comment: @Amy, if you already have a keyboard, then l suggest that you get a tremolo effect pedal and combine with that with an e-piano sound on your keyboard. There are several pedals available under 100$. If you’re in the market for a new keyboard, then I suggest you browse the category of “stage pianos” as those usually come with decent set e-piano sounds such as the Wurlitzer.

Comment: @KrisVanBael thank you so much! I actually do have a piano but it's an acoustic one. so I can't really use a tremolo pedal on it. but I'm planning on buying a digital one so ill do as you recommended. thanks again!!!

Comment: @Amy, so you might consider accepting the answer :-) ?

Answer (score 7):

Some keyboards have a dedicated pitch oscillator on the far left side. If you're playing on a regular piano, it will not be possible.

Comment: [There is a trick to it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IvhVsyA2So)

Answer (score 0):

You can play a note and then the same note one octave up, alternating fast. Or you can play the note and the next fifth, also alternating fast. It will sound like a tremolo.

There is a video demonstrating the effect (The author demonstrates the technique at around [1:45](https://youtu.be/9IvhVsyA2So?t=105)).

Comment: I agree that it could be called tremolo but it doesn't sound anything like the song the question was about.